# @BeforeClass of jUnit is called multiple times

Tags: java, junit

I am new to jUnit, running jUnit testing with `@BeforeClass` and `@Test` methods. The problem is my `@BeforeClass` method is called not once (like it's supposed to) but every time before `@Test` method. Same thing happens with `@AfterClass` - it runs after each `@Test` method. Here's the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import java.util.*;

public class MatrixTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void testAdd() {
    System.out.println("Before class");
}

@Test
public void testValueSet() {
    System.out.println("Hello 1");
}

 @Test
  public void testMultiply() {
    System.out.println("Hello 2");
  }

 @Test
  public void testGetDiagonalSum() {
    System.out.println("Hello 3"); 
   }

Output:
Before class
Hello 3
Before class
Hello 2
Before class
Hello 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are using [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and not [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html)? Also what version of junit is this tested on?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it's @BeforeClass, not Before. The above code is copied and pasted from BlueJ. As for junit version, I'm running it from BlueJ which is updated to the latest version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue here. 
Make sure you are executing by running as JUnit test.

[image: console]

[image: tests]

**Update:**

There is an open bug for Bluej regarding this issue.

Refer to [BLUEJ-437](http://bugs.bluej.org/browse/BLUEJ-437) for more details

Comment: So it's a BlueJ bug then. Now it's clear. Thanks for your help!